# CSFML : Draw Line

Tags: c, graphical-programming

i'm working on a school project using CSFML (The SFML library but in C), i'm trying to display a line between two points but impossible for me to find any good documentation to do it, if someone know how to do it, please help me.

i've got his doc:
https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/graphics-shape-fr.php
and my code look like this:

```
    sfRenderWindow_clear(window.window, sfBlack);
    sfRectangleShape *rectangle = sfRectangleShape_create();
    sfRectangleShape line(rectangle);
    sfRenderWindow_display(window.window);
```

but there is nothing on my window.
The doc tell something like window.draw(); to draw it but it's not recognized as a valid function so...

Thank you

Comment: It's exactly the same as the C++ way of doing it just with the C api.

Comment: i've added a few lines of code on the topic

Comment: You mean like [`sfRenderWindow_drawShape`](https://github.com/SFML/CSFML/blob/master/include/SFML/Graphics/RenderWindow.h#L462)? or `sfRenderWindow_drawRectangleShape`?

Comment: idk, none of these is working..

Comment: when drawing on a surface, the code must tell the function all the necessary coordinates.  for instance, for a rectangle, the x,y starting point (which may be the current cursor position  and if a line, the end x,y coordnate

Comment: one possible reason your code is not working is you did no `#include` the needed header files and/or when compiling/linking did not referendce the associated library